# spacing in cases

Tags: spacing, amsmath, unicode-math, pandoc

This looks pretty awful, what can I do to improve it?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\dd^2 X}{\dd x^2}  & = \alpha X\\
\frac{\dd^2 Y}{\dd y^2}&=-\alpha Y
\end{cases}
$$
\end{document}
```

(Note: I'm using pandoc to convert from markdown to tex, hence the `$$`)

[image]

specifically, I'm unhappy with

- the vertical spacing
- the spacing between the brace and the equations
- the spacing on the left of the equal signs

Comment: Can't reply better right now: phantom vphantom or hphantom from amsmath package is your friend. Search the site, with Google, and I am pretty sure that you will find a solution.

Comment: thanks but I'm hoping there is a global setting to improve things, rather than adding ad hoc markup in the middle of all the equations (it quickly makes the math unreadable).

Comment: I'd start with the fact that this formula isn't `cases`. So, `\left\{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}\right.` would be better semantically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\dd^2 X}{\dd x^2}  & = \alpha X\\[1ex]
\frac{\dd^2 Y}{\dd y^2}&=-\alpha Y
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

There is no excuse whatsoever for having `$$` in LaTeX. If `pandoc` does wrong, fix it. Moreover, `amsmath` should be loaded before `unicode-math`.

The brace is not required to cover the whole block.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the nice trick!

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below tag improves the output slightly:

```
\[
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\dd^2 X}{\dd x^2}  & = \alpha X\\
\noalign{\vskip9pt}
\dfrac{\dd^2 Y}{\dd y^2}&=-\alpha Y
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: thanks, `dfrac` and `\\[0.5em]` improve things, but the brace is now a bit too small and still too close. It's probably a font thing to do with unicode-math

Comment: ``\\[9pt]`` would do the same, with correct syntax.